# Concatenate field value when duplicate rows are found in UNION query

Tags: mysql

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
a.enterprise_id, 
a.enterprise as 'Customer', 
b.source_connection as 'Connection',
    Case When b.source_connection Is Not Null Then 'source_connection'
    End As 'Connection Location',
b.source_connection_id as 'Connection ID'
FROM db.customers a
Left Outer Join db.source_connections b on a.enterprise_id = b.enterprise_id
UNION
SELECT 
a.enterprise_id, 
a.enterprise as 'Customer', 
c.dest_connection as 'Connection',
    Case When c.dest_connection Is Not Null Then 'destination_connection'
    End As 'Connection Location',
c.dest_connection_id as 'Connection ID'
FROM db.customers a
Left Outer Join db.dest_connections c on a.enterprise_id = c.enterprise_id
Order By 
Customer, Connection asc
```

Example of output:

```
Enterprise ID | **Customer** | **Connection** | **Connection Location** | Connection ID 
----------------   -----------  --------------- ---------------- <br />
     19              ACME Corp        Allied AS2    destination_connection       279 
     19              ACME Corp        Allied AS2    source_connection            279
```

When the same Enterprise ID, Customer, Connection, and Customer ID are found in both source_connection and destination_connection tables, I would like to only output one row, but concatenate the value of Connection Location to read "source & destination connection", so it would output like: 
19              ACME Corp        Allied AS2    source & destination connection          279

This will help clean up a lot of duplicate outputs.
Just not sure where to apply this logic.
Thank you!